# How to prevent spawning a new thread in given code block of rust function/closure

Tags: rust, thread-safety

Given that a function or closure is provided as an argument of another function `run`

```rust
fn run<F, O>(f: F) -> O
where
    F: Fn() -> O,
{
    f()
}
```

with the constrains that new threads cannot be spawned in `F` implementation code block?

Is it possible? if possible, how can it be achieved?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is impossible. Spawning a thread is usually harmless (maybe affects performance but shouldn't affect correctness), so if you have a reason spawning is harmful to your program, please include it in your question. But most likely, spawning isn't going to be the only thing that does what you want to avoid.

Comment: It is impossible to put any restrictions on the implementation of f. You can restrict its signature, but implementation can literally do anything. And that's the same in pretty much any language. It is callers responsibility to not mess up.

Comment: In some sense you're right, there isn't the only thing that it avoids,  but first of all, there is no way for the program to learn when the spawned thread completes or otherwise terminates. you have no control of the detached thread created by provided function/closure, it is potentially harmful and but for sure it slow down the performance.

Comment: @bruceyuan again: this is callers responsibility to pass a function that won't break your program. Spawning threads is a small issue. What if someone passes an infinite while loop? Or keep allocating memory until it is completely drained? And so on, and so on. It is impossible to avoid that. If that callback comes from user input that you run on your machine, then spawning threads is the least problem. Generally don't do this, or maybe run the code in a virtual machine. But if it is supposed to be used by some other dev, then let them worry about not breaking stuff.